# Can't use Debian archive repositories, despite having installed debian-archive-keyring and debian-keyring

Tags: debian, apt, repository, public-key

I'm trying to use some Debian Archive repositories in my `sources.list`, for testing purposes. I want to be able to search packages from Debian Sarge.

My `sources.list` looks like that:

```
# Stretch (Debian 9)

deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main

# Jessie (Debian 8)

deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main

# Wheezy (Debian 7)

deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security wheezy/updates main

# Squeeze (Debian 6)
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main non-free contrib
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main non-free contrib
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ squeeze/updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ squeeze/updates main non-free contrib

# Lenny (Debian 5)
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny main non-free contrib
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny main non-free contrib
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ lenny/updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ lenny/updates main non-free contrib

# Etch (Debian 4)
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ etch main non-free contrib
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ etch main non-free contrib
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ etch/updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ etch/updates main non-free contrib

# Sarge (Debian 3.1)
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ sarge main non-free contrib
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ sarge main non-free contrib
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ sarge/updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ sarge/updates main non-free contrib
```

However, when I run `apt update`, I can't retrieve the packages from the Archive repositories (the stable/oldstable/oldoldstable repositories work fine, though), because of public key problems:

```
root@sandbox:~# apt update
Ign:1 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.debian.org/debian squeeze InRelease
Ign:4 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian jessie InRelease
Get:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]
Ign:6 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian wheezy InRelease
Ign:7 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security squeeze/updates InRelease
Hit:8 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Hit:9 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian jessie Release
Hit:10 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian wheezy Release
Ign:11 http://archive.debian.org/debian lenny InRelease
Ign:12 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates InRelease
Ign:13 http://archive.debian.org/debian etch InRelease
Ign:14 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security etch/updates InRelease
Ign:15 http://archive.debian.org/debian sarge InRelease
Ign:17 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security sarge/updates InRelease
Hit:18 http://security.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates InRelease
Get:19 http://archive.debian.org/debian squeeze Release [96.0 kB]
Hit:20 http://security.debian.org/debian-security wheezy/updates InRelease
Get:22 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security squeeze/updates Release [86.9 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.debian.org/debian lenny Release [99.6 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates Release [92.4 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.debian.org/debian etch Release [67.8 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security etch/updates Release [37.6 kB]
Get:28 http://archive.debian.org/debian sarge Release [34.6 kB]
Get:29 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security sarge/updates Release [40.7 kB]
Get:30 http://archive.debian.org/debian squeeze Release.gpg [1,655 B]
Get:31 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security squeeze/updates Release.gpg [836 B]
Get:32 http://archive.debian.org/debian lenny Release.gpg [1,034 B]
Get:33 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates Release.gpg [836 B]
Get:34 http://archive.debian.org/debian etch Release.gpg [1,033 B]
Get:35 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security etch/updates Release.gpg [835 B]
Get:36 http://archive.debian.org/debian sarge Release.gpg [378 B]
Get:37 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security sarge/updates Release.gpg [189 B]
Ign:30 http://archive.debian.org/debian squeeze Release.gpg
Ign:31 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security squeeze/updates Release.gpg
Ign:32 http://archive.debian.org/debian lenny Release.gpg
Ign:33 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates Release.gpg
Ign:34 http://archive.debian.org/debian etch Release.gpg
Ign:35 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security etch/updates Release.gpg
Ign:36 http://archive.debian.org/debian sarge Release.gpg
Ign:37 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security sarge/updates Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org/debian squeeze Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AED4B06F473041FA NO_PUBKEY 64481591B98321F9
E: The repository 'http://archive.debian.org/debian squeeze Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org/debian-security squeeze/updates Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AED4B06F473041FA
E: The repository 'http://archive.debian.org/debian-security squeeze/updates Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org/debian lenny Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AED4B06F473041FA NO_PUBKEY 4D270D06F42584E6
E: The repository 'http://archive.debian.org/debian lenny Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9AA38DCD55BE302B
E: The repository 'http://archive.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org/debian etch Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9AA38DCD55BE302B NO_PUBKEY B5D0C804ADB11277
E: The repository 'http://archive.debian.org/debian etch Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org/debian-security etch/updates Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9AA38DCD55BE302B
E: The repository 'http://archive.debian.org/debian-security etch/updates Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org/debian sarge Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A70DAF536070D3A1 NO_PUBKEY B5D0C804ADB11277
E: The repository 'http://archive.debian.org/debian sarge Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org/debian-security sarge/updates Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A70DAF536070D3A1
E: The repository 'http://archive.debian.org/debian-security sarge/updates Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

All the resources talking about this suggest installing the `debian-keyring` and `debian-archive-keyring` packages, but I already have them and this does not seem to be doing anything.

Does anyone have a solution for that?

Comment: When you get that many versions apart, there's a good chance stuff won't work even if you load it.  Also, there is very little maintenance in the old-stable repository, and virtually none in repositories older than that.  So you risk loading stuff that has not been patched for security issues.

Comment: That's actually the point of this: I want to install old packages to study the vulnerabilities in them. This is for a school project.

Answer (score 2):

From the article
[Fix Apt-get : NO_PUBKEY / GPG Error in Debian](https://ccm.net/faq/809-debian-apt-get-no-pubkey-gpg-error):

> In computers based on a Debian operating system that uses Linux
>   kernel, error messages similar to NO_PUBKEY may appear.This happens
>   while using the Apt-Get command line tool, and this error is
>   associated with the tool's update feature.
>
> This problem can be solved by simply keying in the appropriate
>   commands.

The suggested commands for this fix are (for key server `pgpkeys.mit.edu`):

```
gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key [key-name]
gpg -a --export [key-name] | sudo apt-key add -
```

The keys mentioned in your error messages are: AED4B06F473041FA, 64481591B98321F9,
4D270D06F42584E6, and others (seems like a lot).

Try this advice for one key and check if at least that one error message has now
been resolved. If so, repeat for the other keys.

Comment: Just did that one, but replacing the server with `pool.sks-keyservers.net`, as the MIT one seems to be down. Ran the commands with all the keys without problems, and instead of the "key not found" error, I'm getting that one: `W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org/debian squeeze Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG AED4B06F473041FA Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (6.0/squeeze) <ftpmaster@debian.org> EXPKEYSIG 64481591B98321F9 Squeeze Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>`

Comment: The key `AED4B06F473041FA` seems to be missing.

Comment: No, actually the key `AED4B06F473041FA` is not missing. The message I pasted is only for the first repository, here is the full message: https://pastebin.com/gKhdduYT

Comment: Try apt-get with `--allow-unauthenticated`. See [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732985/force-update-from-unsigned-repository-ubuntu-16-04).

Comment: `--allow-unauthenticated` did not do anything special. However, I tried adding `[trusted=yes]` after the `deb` and `deb-src` on each line, and despite the gpg errors remain, the packages are obtained. But I'd still want to find the cause of this, as putting `[trusted=yes]` everywhere does not sound a healthy option.